# How to modify the following function in python to get the desired output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I was writing a function which takes in a word and return a string with the consonants replaced by _.
But the output wasn't as good as it was thought to be. It would be great if you could help me out of this situation.
The code is:

```
    def replace_letter(word):
        letter_list = word.split()
        print(letter_list)
        new_letter_list = []

        for letter in letter_list:
            if letter not in "aeiou":
                new_letter_list.append("_")
            else:
                new_letter_list.append(letter)

        print(new_letter_list)
        new_word = " ".join(new_letter_list)

        return new_word
    print(replace_word("jaywalk"))
```

Output was:

```
['jaywalk']
['_']
_
```

I hope this information would be sufficient. Please help me out!

Comment: Welcome to the community! You've got a lot of good answers below so I'll just give you a couple of hints. You should try and find out what happens when you do a `.split()` You will find it splits on spaces. That's why you got `['jaywalk']` rather than `['j','a','y','w','a','l','k']`. Next, you should try to understand how to iteration works in python. Your for loop runs only once because the `new_letter_list` has only one element: the whole string 'jaywalk'. On the 1st iteration, letter='jawallk' and 'jawallk' is not in 'aeiou'

Comment: Finally, to iterate over a string, you don't really need to make it into a list. In python, a sting is iterable. Try to do `for ch in "Hello World": print(ch);` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_letter (word):
    new_letter_list = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in "aeiou":
            new_letter_list.append("_")
        else:
            new_letter_list.append(letter)
    new_word = " ".join(new_letter_list)
    return new_word

print(replace_letter ("jaywalk"))
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, using built-in [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
" ".join(map(lambda x: x if x in "aeiou" else "_", "jaywalk"))
```

list comprehension,

```
" ".join([v if v in "aeiou" else "_" for v in "jaywalk"])
```

output,

```
_ a _ _ a _ _
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xyz]')
re.sub(pattern,"_","jaywalk")
```

The result will be '_a__a__'